# Was God discovered or did He reveal Himself?

Tags: nature-of-god, history, genesis, general-revelation

If He was revealed, why did He wait so long to reveal Himself? Humans have been around for 100,000+ years.

Comment: You may like to narrow your question. Do you want the view of a particular denomination? A particular view of history? For example, a young earth creationist would dispute your timeline of 100,000 years, and have God revealing himself immediately to Adam, hence there was no wait involved.

Comment: Hi Chloe! It looks like you're trying to get an absolute answer to this question. Unfortunately, since different groups of Christians will have different answers, your question isn't in a form we can give an objective answer to. You could rephrase to ask for the opinion of a specific group. Or you could ask whether some group believes he revealed himself, and then ask in a separate question what arguments those groups use. It's a good question - but it needs rephrasing before we can answer it. Ask me for help if you need.

Comment: Each individual discovers the fact of revelation themselves when God, himself, is revealed to them, individually.

Comment: According to the Bible God had a perfect relationship with Adam and Eve from the beginning.  Later, He made a promise of a coming Saviour on the very day that Adam and Eve sinned... Genesis 3:15. Adam and Eve must have passed the knowledge of this to their descendants else men could not have called on the name of the LORD and been saved before the flood (Genesis 4:26).  A relationship with God could have been enjoyed by believers of this promise.  So "Enoch walked with God" (Gen 5:24) & Job lived righteously before God before the time of Moses & so had not much written revelation to live by.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to scripture, God revealed himself in the beginning by creating.

> In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth. [Genesis 1:1, KJV.]

Then God revealed himself to humanity, by speaking.

> And the LORD God commanded the man, saying, Of every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat: [Genesis 2:16, KJV.]

God revealed himself to Adam, to Abel, to Enoch, to Noah, to Job, to Abraham, to Isaac, to Jacob, to Joseph.

And then revealed himself out of the midst of a flame, within a bush that was not consumed, to Moses :

> I am that I am. [Exodus 3:14, KJV.]

In the nature of God, it is impossible to 'discover' God.

He reveals himself.

Comment: This is what my pastor said (southern Baptist), and that humans are 10,000 years old (around 8,000 BC). However, I disagree with that. That's barely enough time for the pyramids and the Pharaohs, let alone Indian and Chinese history.

Comment: @Chloe Have a look at the ages of the most ancient, available, coherent,written records.  And compare that with the time of the Flood in the days of Noah.

Answer (score 0):

**He is Not Silent** Francis Schaeffer wrote a book entitled, "He is There and He is Not Silent." It highlighted the fact of Divine Revelation, that is the initiative displayed by a communicative God.

Along those lines there is a book entitled, "Dialogue with Deity" (Raymond Grant, Christian Faith Publishing) that commented on *every instance* in the book of Genesis--the first book in the Bible-- where God talked to man and man talked to God! From the first, the Holy Bible shows God to be self-revealing---no matter the age of the earth and existence of mankind.

> He who created the mouth, could He not speak? And He who created the ear, could He not listen?

This is what the Jewish prophets presented as an argument for the existence of a communicating God, as opposite to deaf and dumb idols. So for a creating God to be able to reveal His will and principles to man was a given.

**General Revelation** The Holy Bible not only declared God to be talkative (self-revealing), it also declares that God's existence can be known (discovered by thoughtful men) by Natural Theology or General Revelation: the observation of the Universe with all its "just-so" parts, delicate details needed for life, physical balance of nature, etc. that scream **Creator**. Randomness, chance-formations, etc. fall far short of valid explanations for the existence of all the universe. (Romans 1, Acts 17:16-34; as well as many O.T. verses, are references to the amazing universe that "speaks" to us...sings to us! See Psalm 104:24-30) In this way man may have "discovered" God who left His fingerprints all over the universe.

So whether, by direct Divine revelation, or by General revelation (Natural Theology), God has made Himself known.

The idea of a tribal witchdoctor "coming up with" the Idea of an angry god who must be appeased or the volcanos will explode---which is taught in most universities!---lacks credibility. No one ever gives the name of the witchdoctor, or the name of the tribe involved, nor the date when it happened!!  God wasn't "discovered" in this sense or way. The initiative of discovery was on God's part...from the Beginning.